# Why is the Google Chrome inspector adding weird id attributes to random html elements?

Tags: html, google-chrome, localhost

I have the following page running on my localhost:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Times</title>
  <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    input{font:1.5em/1.1em sans-serif;padding:0.25em;}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <p>
    <input type="date" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="time" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="datetime" />
  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

When I viewed the page in Chrome and looked at the inspector, I noticed there were some id attributes added to three of the elements:

[image]

Anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Chrome Inspector is not adding those attributes. It's showing that *something else* has added them.

It's almost certainly an extension you have installed. Maybe this one:

[image]

Disable your extensions (@ `chrome://extensions`) or view your page in an Incognito window (assuming you haven't enabled extensions in Incognito, of course) and take a second look.

Comment: Yep. It's the DoNotTrackMe extension (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/donottrackme-online-priva/epanfjkfahimkgomnigadpkobaefekcd). Thanks!